# Object.defineProperty - scope and use inside function returning object?

Tags: javascript, properties, scope

I'm learning JavaScript (using latest Google Chrome build on 64bit Debian Jessie) for a couple of days now and right now I'm stuck in understanding how exactly `Object.defineProperty` works. I have the following page:

```
function createPerson() {
    var person = {
        firstName: 'Lilly',
        lastName: 'Louis',
    };

    Object.defineProperty(person, 'fullName', {
        get: function() {
            return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
        },
        set: function(name) {
            var words = name.split(' ');
            this.firstName = words[0] || '';
            this.lastName = words[1] || '';
        }
    });
}

var p1 = createPerson();
console.log("Person's default name is \"" + p1.fullName + "\"");
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fullName' of undefined` at the line where I try to use the property inside `console.log(...)`. If I place both the definition of `person` along with the `Object.defineProperty` outside the function everything works fine. If I move **only** `Object.defineProperty` outside the function after `p1` is created like this:

```
var p1 = createPerson();
Object.defineProperty(p1, 'fullName', {
    get: function() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },
    set: function(name) {
        var names = name.split(' ');
        this.firstName = names[0] || '';
        this.lastName = names[1] || '';
    }
});
```

I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object` followed by the console pointing out that it is invoked on an `(anonymous function)` (that is `p1`) which is even more confusing since I've just read that if I assign `callPerson` to my `p1` without the brackets I'm passing the function object to it otherwise I'm calling the function itself and assigning its return value (if none, *undefined* is returned) to `p1`.

I have the feeling both issues are completely separate but still since I'm not 100% sure I've decided to put both in the same question. Any advice what I'm doing wrong here? I can define my `getter` and `setter` the old fashioned way by simply doing

```
function createPerson() {
    var person = {
        firstName: 'Lilly',
        lastName: 'Louis',
        getFullName: function() {
            return ...;
        }
        setFullName: function(name) {
            ...
        }
    };
}
```

but I would like to understand what's going on here. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `defineProperty` call is absolutely fine. The problem is that `createPerson` never returns anything, so the result of calling it is `undefined`. You want `return person;` at the end:

```js
function createPerson() {
  var person = {
    firstName: 'Lilly',
    lastName: 'Louis',
  };

  Object.defineProperty(person, 'fullName', {
    get: function() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },
    set: function(name) {
      var words = name.split(' ');
      this.firstName = words[0] || '';
      this.lastName = words[1] || '';
    }
  });
  
  return person; // <=======
}

var p1 = createPerson();
console.log("Person's default name is \"" + p1.fullName + "\"");
```

Alternately, make it a *constructor* function (used with `new`) rather than a factory function, and use `this` within the function. In that case, we'd drop `create` from the name, and we wouldn't (typically) use `return this;` at the end because if the function doesn't return a different object, by default the result of `new XYZ` is the object created by the `new` operator and supplied to the function as `this`:

```js
function Person() {
  this.firstName = 'Lilly';
  this.lastName = 'Louis';

  Object.defineProperty(this, 'fullName', {
    get: function() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },
    set: function(name) {
      var words = name.split(' ');
      this.firstName = words[0] || '';
      this.lastName = words[1] || '';
    }
  });
}

var p1 = new Person();
console.log("Person's default name is \"" + p1.fullName + "\"");
```

Comment: *facepalm* Christ, I have deleted it in my code (and here) while moving code around. So stupid of me...Thanks for point that out.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you created a `person` variable, but never returned it. Hence nothing is being returned from the function, and the assignment is undefined:

```
function createPerson() {
    var person = {
        firstName: 'Lilly',
        lastName: 'Louis',
    };

    Object.defineProperty(person, 'fullName', {
        get: function() { return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName; },
        set: function(name) {
            var words = name.split(' ');
            this.firstName = words[0] || '';
            this.lastName = words[1] || '';
        }
    });
    return person; // Add this line
}
```